# I don't know where I am going wrong with BigIntegers

Tags: java

Below is my code for `BigInteger`, I don't know where I am going wrong, can someone please correct my code please?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter BigInteger number : ");
        BigInteger nbn = num.nextBigInteger();

        for(BigInteger count = BigInteger.ZERO;
                count.compareTo(nbn) <= 0;
                count.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not mentioned what the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign value of `count.add(BigInteger.ONE)` back to `count`:

```
for (BigInteger count = BigInteger.ZERO;
        count.compareTo(nbn) <= 0;
        count = count.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: @PiyushRaghatate [Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)